# Define Promise As ES6 Class Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Using ES6 syntax to define a class and its methods, how can I define a method as a Promise, without having to wrap it in a regular function that returns a promise?  I want to do something like the following below:

```
class PromiseMethod {

   promiseMethod = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        return resolve();
   }
}
```

Comment: *"how can I define a method as a Promise"* Methods (i.e. functions) are something that can be called. Promises cannot be called. What you want doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Probably meant a property?

Answer (score 6):

Promises are just an object *returned* from a function — whether it be a method or not doesn't matter. Try this:

```
class Something {
  promiseMethod () {
    return new Promise(...);
  }
}

(new Something).promiseMethod().then(...)
```

But maybe you wanted to *not* have to call the method and be able to use the Promise methods directly? In this case, it's not a method, it's a *property*:

```
class Something {
  constructor () {
    this.promiseProperty = new Promise(...);
  }
}

(new Something).promiseProperty.then(...);
```

Comment: Hi, what if you need to chain another promise method that belongs to the class. `(new Something).promiseMethod().then( (new Something).anotherPromiseMethod() ).then(...)` ?

Comment: @shangyeshen you should really ask another question, but given the insight is the same… `.then()` takes **a function**. A Promise is **an object**. So you need either `.then(anotherFunction)` or `.then(() => anotherFunction())` (they do the same thing, but the second form allows you to control arguments better, e.g. `.then((a, b) => anotherFunction(b, a))`).